# One-to-many relationship: Update removed children with JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship.

0 or 1 **client** <-> List of 0 or more **product orders**.

That relationship should be set or unset on both entities:
On the client side, I want to set the List of product orders assigned to the client; the client should then be set / unset to the orders chosen automatically.
On the product order side, I want to set the client to which the oder is assigned; that product order should then be removed from its previously assiged client's list and added to the new assigned client's list.

I want to use pure JPA 2.0 annotations and one "merge" call to the entity manager only (with cascade options). I've tried with the following code pieces, but it doesn't work (I use EclipseLink 2.2.0 as persistence provider)

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductOrder> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setOrders(List<ProductOrder> orders) {
        for (ProductOrder order : this.orders) {
            order.unsetClient();
            // don't use order.setClient(null);
            // (ConcurrentModificationEx on array)
            // TODO doesn't work!
        }
        for (ProductOrder order : orders) {
            order.setClient(this);
        }
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    // other fields / getters / setters
}

@Entity
public class ProductOrder implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Client client;

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        // remove from previous client
        if (this.client != null) {
            this.client.getOrders().remove(this);
        }

        this.client = client;

        // add to new client
        if (client != null && !client.getOrders().contains(this)) {
            client.getOrders().add(this);
        }
    }

    public void unsetClient() {
        client = null;
    }

    // other fields / getters / setters
}
```

Facade code for persisting client:

```
// call setters on entity by JSF frontend...
getEntityManager().merge(client)
```

Facade code for persisting product order:

```
// call setters on entity by JSF frontend...
getEntityManager().merge(productOrder)
```

When changing the client assignment on the order side, it works well: On the client side, the order gets removed from the previous client's list and is added to the new client's list (if re-assigned).

BUT **when changing on the client side, I can only add orders** (on the order side, assignment to the new client is performed), but it just ignores when I remove orders from the client's list (after saving and refreshing, they are still in the list on the client side, and on the order side, they are also still assigned to the previous client.

Just to clarify, I **DO NOT want to use a "delete orphan" option**: When removing an order from the list, it should not be deleted from the database, but its client assignment should be updated (that is, to null), as defined in the Client#setOrders method. How can this be archieved?

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to the help I received here, I was able to fix this problem. See my solution below:

The client (**"One" / "owned" side**) stores the orders that have been modified in a temporary field.

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable, EntityContainer {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductOrder> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    private List<ProductOrder> modifiedOrders = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setOrders(List<ProductOrder> orders) {
    if (orders == null) {
        orders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    modifiedOrders = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ProductOrder order : this.orders) {
        order.unsetClient();
        modifiedOrders.add(order);
        // don't use order.setClient(null);
        // (ConcurrentModificationEx on array)
    }

    for (ProductOrder order : orders) {
        order.setClient(this);
        modifiedOrders.add(order);
    }

    this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override // defined by my EntityContainer interface
    public List getContainedEntities() {
        return modifiedOrders;
}
```

On the **facade**, when persisting, it checks if there are any entities that must be persisted, too. Note that I used an interface to encapsulate this logic as my facade is actually generic.

```
// call setters on entity by JSF frontend...
getEntityManager().merge(entity);

if (entity instanceof EntityContainer) {
    EntityContainer entityContainer = (EntityContainer) entity;
    for (Object childEntity : entityContainer.getContainedEntities()) {
        getEntityManager().merge(childEntity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA does not do this and as far as I know there is no JPA implementation that does this either.  JPA requires you to manage both sides of the relationship.  When only one side of the relationship is updated this is sometimes referred to as "object corruption"

JPA does define an "owning" side in a two-way relationship (for a OneToMany this is the side that does NOT have the mappedBy annotation) which it uses to resolve a conflict when persisting to the database (there is only one representation of this relationship in the database compared to the two in memory so a resolution must be made).  This is why changes to the ProductOrder class are realized but not changes to the Client class.

Even with the "owning" relationship you should always update both sides.  This often leads people to relying on only updating one side and they get in trouble when they turn on the second-level cache.  In JPA the conflicts mentioned above are only resolved when an object is persisted and reloaded from the database.  Once the 2nd level cache is turned on that may be several transactions down the road and in the meantime you'll be dealing with a corrupted object.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation of how the "owning side" affects conflict resolution. Now I understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also merge the Orders that you removed, just merging the Client is not enough.

The issue is that although you are changing the Orders that were removed, you are never sending these orders to the server, and never calling merge on them, so there is no way for you changes to be reflected.

You need to call merge on each Order that you remove.  Or process your changes locally, so you don't need to serialize or merge any objects.

EclipseLink does have a bidirectional relationship maintenance feature which may work for you in this case, but it is not part of JPA.

Comment: In this case (or even generally), will adding a cascade on the Orders help (so when Client is merged, Order gets merged automatically) ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to add the new property on your ProductOrder, I named it `detached` in the following examples.

When you want to detach the order from the client you can use a callback on the order itself:

```
@Entity public class ProductOrder implements Serializable { 
  /*...*/

  //in your case this could probably be @Transient
  private boolean detached;  

  @PreUpdate
  public void detachFromClient() {
    if(this.detached){
        client.getOrders().remove(this);
        client=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of deleting the orders you want to delete you set detached to true. When you will merge & flush the client,  the entity manager will detect the modified order and execute the @PreUpdate callback effectively detaching the order from the client.

Comment: Good idea. Because I actually want to delete orders, I used a similar mechanism with the `@PreRemove` annotation.