# JPA - How to remove only the relationship in a OneToMany?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, relationship

Well, I'm in trouble and I can't find any question about it.
I have an entity that has an OneToMany relationship with another. I tried removing the 'another' from the one's List. After that, I tried merging that one. But it just doesn't work.
I don't want to remove the 'another' from the database, I just want to remove it from the one's list.

This is my code:

```
public class ParametrosVingentes implements Serializable {

    // ...
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.class, cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name="ImportacaoZeusVingentes",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="parametros_vingentes_fk"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="agendamento_fk")
    )
    private List<AgendamentoImportacaoZeus> agendamentosImportacaoZeus;

    // ...

}
```

AgendamentoImportacaoZeus is the 'another' entity.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name = "AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.listarPorDataCriacao", query = "SELECT a FROM AgendamentoImportacaoZeus a ORDER BY a.dataCriacao DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.getPorData", query="SELECT a FROM AgendamentoImportacaoZeus a WHERE a.agendamento = :data"),
    @NamedQuery(name="AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.vingentes", query="SELECT ag FROM ParametrosVingentes p JOIN p.agendamentosImportacaoZeus ag WHERE p.id = :id")
})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "SEQ_AG_IMP_ZEUS")
public class AgendamentoImportacaoZeus implements Serializable, Agendamento {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ")
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCriacao;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date agendamento;

    // ...
```

The code that merges the entity:

```
ParametrosVingentes parametrosVingentes = parametrosVingentesDao.buscar(ParametrosVingentes.ID);
List<? extends Agendamento> agendamentosVingentes;
// ...
agendamentosVingentes = parametrosVingentes.getAgendamentosImportacaoZeus();
// ...
for(int i=0; i<agendamentosVingentes.size(); i++){
    if(agendamentosVingentes.get(i).getAgendamento().compareTo(dataAgendamentoDesmarcar) == 0){
        agendamentosVingentes.remove(i);
        break;
    }
}
// ...
entityManager.merge(parametrosVingentes);
```

Removing the entity from the collection and merging it should remove the RELATIONSHIP, or shouldn't it?

I debugged the code and after merge, I have the list of AgendamentoImportacaoZeus without the element I have removed. But when I get the ParametrosVingentes from the database, it's there again.

The entityManager is controlled by Spring. The method is Transactional. Then I think that it's flushing normally.

Thanks for attention.

UPDATE:

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634755/one-to-many-relationship-update-removed-children-with-jpa-2-0/) and tried to change my mapping. Now I have the following:

```
@Entity
public class ParametrosVingentes implements Serializable {

    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parametrosVingentes", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<AgendamentoImportacaoZeus> agendamentosImportacaoZeus;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name = "AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.listarPorDataCriacao", query = "SELECT a FROM AgendamentoImportacaoZeus a ORDER BY a.dataCriacao DESC"),
    @NamedQuery(name="AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.getPorData", query="SELECT a FROM AgendamentoImportacaoZeus a WHERE a.agendamento = :data"),
    @NamedQuery(name="AgendamentoImportacaoZeus.vingentes", query="SELECT ag FROM ParametrosVingentes p JOIN p.agendamentosImportacaoZeus ag WHERE p.id = :id")
})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "SEQ_AG_IMP_ZEUS")
public class AgendamentoImportacaoZeus implements Serializable, Agendamento {

    // ...
    private ParametrosVingentes parametrosVingentes;
    // ...

}
```

I am trying this:

```
Agendamento agendamento = null;
for(int i=0; i<agendamentosVingentes.size(); i++){
    if(agendamentosVingentes.get(i).getAgendamento().compareTo(dataAgendamentoDesmarcar) == 0){
        agendamento = agendamentosVingentes.remove(i);
        agendamento.setParametrosVingentes(null);
        break;
    }
}
entityManager.merge(parametrosVingentes);
entityManager.merge(agendamento);
```

Do someone know why it's not updating?

Comment: You shouldn't even have to merge if you work on an attached entity. Are you sure the getter doesn't return a copy of the list, instead of returning the list instead? Could you show your real code, because the above code would throw a ConcurrentModificationException given you remove an element from the list you're iterating on.

Comment: I have a 'break' on the loop I didn't post. I'll update the code.

Comment: I think your question is answered there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634755/one-to-many-relationship-update-removed-children-with-jpa-2-0/

Comment: Please post the code of the other entity (AgendamentoImportacaoZeus).